# Refactoring database should I use surrogate key?

Tags: database, refactoring, relational-database

I inherited an Access database that I'm migrating to SQL Server. In the database there are a lot of labelling or classification columns. For example an order table may have a status attribute, a supplier may have a rating attribute. Most have no real business logic to them, they are not entities in themselves, they are all just descriptors to allow a user to label and search with.

On one hand I think that these descriptors should be placed in their own table and referenced using foreign keys. And then in my application code I can use enums that match the surrogate id. Why? Because I can add to them easily, change the value easily, maybe save some space.

```
Order { OrderId int, CustomerId int, StatusId int}
Status { StatusId int, Name varchar(50)}
```

On the other hand because many of these attributes will never change, will never be added to and I have a bunch of other stuff to do I think I should just leave it.

```
Order{OrderId int, CustomerId int, Status varchar(50)}
```

Is the first option above the way it should always be done? Is the second option acceptable? The only downside I see to leaving it as is is that the table will be a little larger and that a string comparison may not be as fast as int comparison.

Comment: normalise till it hurts, etc etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need more control over the values you find in that "Status" column, you could also insert distinct values from Order.Status into another table, and set a foreign key reference to it.  To follow your way of describing the tables . . .

```
Order{OrderId int, CustomerId int, Status varchar(50)}
Status {Name varchar(50)}
```

I'd choose something more descriptive than "Name" for that column, though. Whether you cascade updates or deletes is application-dependent. When you're on SQL Server, you can control who is allowed to update the "Status" table with SQL GRANT and REVOKE statements.  (You can do that with Access, too, but you seem to be moving away from that.)

To get meaningful data from this table requires two joins instead of three. Think about whether you need 50 characters in that column. (Access defaults to 50. Most people never change it.)

Now, to answer your questions, the first option above is not the way it should *always* be done. ID numbers always increase the number of joins required, and you still need a UNIQUE constraint on the natural key.  It doesn't make any sense to use ID numbers for things like USA state codes, ZIP codes, etc.  The second option isn't usually acceptable to me; I'd *usually* reference another table with a foreign key like I did at the top of this answer.